# Is there anything wrong with my post request?

Tags: jquery, post

I am trying to create a simple post request but I can't get the response from the server as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with it but I might be wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.post("http://myurl.com/receiver/", { name: "Sean", email: "myemail@domain.com" }, function(data){
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(result);
            alert(result);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

opening Chrome dev tools gives me:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl.com/receiver/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I tried uploading to my server or running chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`but I get the same message

Comment: What do your browser tools say?

Comment: ah yes sorry forgot to add that hold on, I'll update

Comment: You probably need to give some insight into what is supposed to happen on the serer receiving the request.  Outside of needing clarification on whether this is a cross-domain request, I don't see any issue with the javascript here.

Comment: yes from my domain to another that's true, that's not possible right? is there a work around to create a post request?

Comment: Yes, do it from your server, not the browser.

Comment: The only other possible solution is to use CORS

Comment: You can make cross domain requests and get jsonp back as analternative to regular json

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript